# What name is Michael shouting in the Improv class?

Tags: dialogue, the-office

*The Office* (S02E9): “[Email Surveillance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_Surveillance)”

Michael goes to his improv class, the teacher asks for volunteers and Michael is the first to raise his hand, and he shouts something like:

> “Mr Cartair! Mr Cartair!”

What is he actually saying, and what is it a reference to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He's emulating a line from a tv show, *Welcome Back, Kotter* so what he is actually saying is "Mr Kotter, Mr Kotter".

> Michael: [In Horshack voice from 'Welcome Back, Kotter'] Ooo Ooo Ooo Ooo, Mr. Cart-air, Mr. Cart-air.

Read more in [the transcript](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=574&t=25316).

Comment: Of course, _Welcome Back, Kotter_ takes place in NYC, so Horshack has a strong NY accent so it's more "Mista Kah-tah, Mista Kah-tah" New Yawkas tend to drop their `r`s

Comment: @FreeMan There were a number of New York accents exhibited in that show. Barbarino's Italian-American accent is quite different from Horshack's (his ethnicity is ambiguous).

Comment: I think Horshack is somewhat generically from The Bronx (as is my mom & family), but... it's been a few moons since I last watched the show, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: I always thought it was **Washington** who, with a heavy NYC "jive" accent would say "Mister Kot-taire!" https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072582/characters/nm0385320?ref_=tt_cl_c_7

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer   agreed.  Paulie should update his answer

Comment: I'll also add that this is right in Michael's wheelhouse of rather dated references to 70's and 80's TV, alongside his other references to Sanford & Son, "Where's the beef?", and classic SNL sketches.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger But "Ooo Ooo..." was definitely Horshack. And the answer is quoting the transcript literally.